# Making an ui to be adaptable in various iOS devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface

How to make my ui to be adaptable in all iOS devices.While researching , I saw few code where they've defined the sizes of various devices and designed the ui based on the size values. A sample code of how it is defines is as follows,

```
#define SCREEN_WIDTH ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)
#define SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH (MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
#define SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH (MIN(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
#define IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0)
```

Its tedious, if I have to detect size each time. In case of android, there exists fragments to make ui work with various screen size. Is there any alternative for fragments in iOS and How to make my ui to be adaptable in various devices?

Comment: El Captain's answer is quite comprehensive. But I would add: you need to use the Storyboard + autolayouts. Storyboard is a tool to graphically lay out the UI and user's path through your iOS app. You'll be able to make your UI fit/resize all the iPhone/iPad screens. For more info just google "iOS Stroryboard autolayouts sample".

Comment: And don't forget about _Size Classes_. See: [Adaptivity and Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html)

Comment: Buddy you have to go with AutoLayout . . . . .Previously I was creating all the UI by code for make it work in all devices. . . But Apple introduces Autolayout.I started learning from google . .in a month I became handy to this and Now with autolayout I can create one design for all . . .it will work fine in all devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I have one solution for you what i am using in my project.

I am using one simple mathematical equation to do this.

```
CGRectMake(0, 0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width*100/320, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height*100/568);
```

Here i have one view and according to 5s i want it's size with (100x100) so i give that condition that will take size according to screen size increase or decrease.

In 5s it will take 100x100

In 6 it will take (375*100/320) Width and (667*100/568) Height

May be this will help you.

Comment: 375*100/320 is 117.1875, you're gonna end up with blurry edges with this. You should at least round your computations.

Comment: ya for that we have to use round method